# I want to change the table width 383px into correct percentage value

Tags: html, css

```
<TABLE ID="table001" width="383px" STYLE="border-width:0px;margin-bottom:6pt;margin-top:4pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-style:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<TR STYLE="height:13px;">
<TD STYLE="width:14px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;"></TD>
<TD STYLE="width:202px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;"></TD>
<TD STYLE="width:45px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;">
<P STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size:8pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-indent:0;"><FONT STYLE="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">FY 2015</FONT></P>
</TD>
<TD STYLE="width:18px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;"></TD>
<TD STYLE="width:45px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;">
<P STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size:8pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-indent:0;"><FONT STYLE="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">FY 2014</FONT></P>
</TD>
<TD STYLE="width:14px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:0px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;"></TD>
<TD STYLE="width:45px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:0px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:0px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0px;padding-bottom:3px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:3px;vertical-align:bottom;">
<P STYLE="font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-size:8pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-indent:0;"><FONT STYLE="font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;">FY 2013</FONT></P>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

I have change the table width as 38% (i.e. 383px/10 =38% calcuation), but it's not correct value.

Comment: You have to know to width of the table container in order to get the correct value : percent = table_width * 100 / table_container_width

Comment: Side-question: why do you set your styles inline and not separately?

Comment: percent = table_width * 100 / table_container_width

percent = 383px*100/100%

Is this correct?

Comment: @BSubramani you need the table container width in a constant value for this to work. E.g.: 383px*100/1200px = 31.9%

Comment: Thanks it's working.

Comment: We need to work out this without constant value.